# Is there any way to stop the logs being stored in database using drf-api-tracking in django?

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created a small project using Django, And to check the logs in Database, I have installed the **drf-api-tracking** library from Django. I have passed the LoggingMixin parameter into all classes in views.py file in Django.
I am able to view the logs in db. If I prefer not to write those logs for sometime in db, Is there a way to stop it, rather than uninstalling and removing the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Override the should_log method and customize to your needs.

for example

```
class MyLoggingView(LoggingMixin, APIView):
    def should_log(self, request, response):
        """
        Log only if response contains 'log'
        """
        return 'log' in response.data
```

or in your case

```
class UserViewSet(LoggingMixin, APIView):
    
    def should_log(self, request, response):
        return False
    
    def get(self,request, format=None):
        data=App.objects.all()
        serializer=AppSerializer(data,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: How can I Proceed with this, 

I have added LoggingMixin to class and next what can be done?

class UserViewSet(APIView):

    def get(self,request, format=None):
        data=App.objects.all()
        serializer=AppSerializer(data,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)